# Form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see my demo [here](http://neginph.com/mysite/test). `required_valid()` doesn't work after I click on the "Click Me" button. There are two `<form>` elements after I click on "Click Me", I use of two form, how can I fix this problem?

```
....

 $('.submit').live('submit', function() {
        var passed = true;
        passed = autocomplet_valid() && passed;
        passed = ticket_check() && passed;
        passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
        passed = required_valid() && passed;
        if (!passed) {
            $('#loadingDiv, #overlay').hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I, probably like many others, am very _very_ confused by your question. Can you please reword it and add more detail so it's apparent what's going on?

Comment: Have you considered using a validation plugin? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ is pretty nice.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I don't want use of plugin.

Comment: You already use jQuery - so why write something already available in a pretty nice way from scratch

Answer (score 0):

currently your demo isn't working because you have no element with the id of "clock" and you're getting this error:

```
test (line 42)
document.getElementById("clock") is null
[Break On This Error] document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: did that fix it? also on your page the file "get_ticket_code" is not found when you run the post ajax to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about just handling the button click?

```
$("form.submit button").click(...);
```

By the way, can you restructure your HTML to not having a nested `<form>`? The first one doesn't really have form elements i.e. only one link.